# Play sound from background

Tags: iphone, background, audio

If my app goes in background I can continue to play sound but only if the sound start before the background state, but if my app is already in background when the sound start (alarm for example) I can't?   Right?

Maybe is a stupid question but i'am a little bit confused!

PS: Thanks jandjorgensen to correct my english. (Maybe it's obvious but it's not my mother language)